# QML WebEngineView doesn't play YouTube video if the video hasn't 480p quality

Tags: youtube, qml, qwebengineview

The program was written using version Qt 6.4.3
**CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(youtube_video VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick WebEngineQuick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appyoutube_video
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appyoutube_video
    URI youtube_video
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
set_target_properties(appyoutube_video PROPERTIES
#    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.appyoutube_video
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appyoutube_video
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick Qt6::WebEngineQuick
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS appyoutube_video
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

**main.cpp** file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngineQuick/qtwebenginequickglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QtWebEngineQuick::initialize();
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/youtube_video/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed, &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Main.qml** file:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window
import QtWebEngine

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/cabBXCq7_P8"
    }
}
```

Shows a preview after launch:

[after launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsuHE.png)

But trying to play the video results in an error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB2eI.png)

If change **url** to: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cabBXCq7_P8"

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window
import QtWebEngine

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    WebEngineView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cabBXCq7_P8" //"https://www.youtube.com/embed/cabBXCq7_P8"
    }
}
```

We will receive a message:

```
You browser can't play this video
```

[can't play this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JipQL.png)

Can anyone tell me what the error is and how to fix it?

As a result, the video is expected to play

Comment: It seems that this error is more related to Youtube than to QML